# Will this Java regex return a single result or multiple

Tags: java, regex

If my HTML is:

```
<tr><td>....</td><hr></tr>
<tr><td>....</td><hr></tr>
<tr><td>....</td><hr></tr>
<tr><td>....</td><hr></tr>
<tr><td>....</td><hr></tr>
<tr><td>....</td><hr></tr>
```

If my regex is:

```
Patterp p = Pattern.compile("<tr>(.*)<hr></tr>");
```

Should this get 1 result or all the individual rows?

Is there a way to force it to get all the rows and not just the entire html from the top `<tr>` to the last instance of `<hr></tr>` ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your regex is using `.*` which is *greedy*. Try using `.*?` instead. A greedy match will grab as *much* as it can before matching following tokens, so it will go find the last `<hr>` in your source text. A non-greedy match will grab as *little* as it can before matching the next token(s).

Then, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) for more information about parsing HTML with regular expressions.

Comment: Are you guys familiar with HtmlParser? Its in java?  if so, I can post my issue that I am having.

Comment: Post the question (as a new question of course!!!).  I'm sure someone will be familiar enough to answer it.